# Translate 3d object center coordinates to 2d visible viewport coordinates

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I have loaded an wavefront object in Iphone OpenGL.

[image]

It can be rotated around x/y axis, panned around, zoomed in/out.

My task is - when object is tapped, highlight it's 2d center coordinates on screen for example like this:  (Imagine that + is in the center of visible object.)
[image]

When loading OpenGL object I store it's:

1. object center position in world,
2. x,y,z position offset,
3. x,y,z rotation,
4. zoom scale.

When user taps on the screen, I can distinguish which object was tapped. But - as user can tap anywhere on object - Tapped point is not center.

**When user touches an object, I want to be able to find out corresponding object visible approximate center coordinates.**

**How can I do that?**

Most code in google I could find is meant - to translate 3d coordinates to 2d but without rotation.

Some variables in code:

```
Vertex3D centerPosition;  
Vertex3D currentPosition;
Rotation3D currentRotation;

//centerPosition.x,  centerPosition.y, centerPosition.z
//currentPosition.x,  currentPosition.y, currentPosition.z
//currentRotation.x,  currentRotation.y, currentRotation.z
```

Thank You in advance.

(To find out which object I tapped - re-color each object in different color, thus I know what color user tapped.)

**object drawSelf function:**

```
// Save the current transformation by pushing it on the stack
glPushMatrix();

// Load the identity matrix to restore to origin
glLoadIdentity();

// Translate to the current position
glTranslatef(currentPosition.x, currentPosition.y, currentPosition.z);

// Rotate to the current rotation
glRotatef(currentRotation.x, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glRotatef(currentRotation.y, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glRotatef(currentRotation.z, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);


// Enable and load the vertex array
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexNormals);
// Loop through each group

if (textureCoords != NULL)
{
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glTexCoordPointer(valuesPerCoord, GL_FLOAT, 0, textureCoords);
}
for (OpenGLWaveFrontGroup *group in groups)
{
    if (textureCoords != NULL && group.material.texture != nil)
        [group.material.texture bind];
    // Set color and materials based on group's material
    Color3D ambient = group.material.ambient;
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, (const GLfloat *)&ambient);

    Color3D diffuse = group.material.diffuse;
    glColor4f(diffuse.red, diffuse.green, diffuse.blue, diffuse.alpha);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE,  (const GLfloat *)&diffuse);

    Color3D specular = group.material.specular;
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, (const GLfloat *)&specular);

    glMaterialf(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, group.material.shininess);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3*group.numberOfFaces, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, &(group.faces[0]));
}
if (textureCoords != NULL)
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
// Restore the current transformation by popping it off
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: you'll have to do the steps that the OpenGL pipeline performs for each vertex yourself for the object center. this includes transforming the object center to clip coordinates ( multiply with 4x4 projection, view & model matrices - you have those for sure somewhere in your code, because you need them in your vertex shader anyway ), then the perspective division and lastly applying the viewport transformation.

Comment: Ok, so step by step - I start at zero position with no rotations/movements. Now what? I calculate 2d coordinates or apply one OpenGL pipeline step (i.e. rotation) ?

Comment: ok, I should have asked this before I posted the above comment: are you working directly with OpenGL ES, or are you using some wrapper framework / library? because I assumed that you work with OpenGL directly - this would include building the transformation matrices yourself, compiling shaders, generating vertex buffers for the object etc.; basically, you need to show a bit more code: how do you actually apply transformations to your cube & how do you draw it?

Comment: Sorry, Yes I am working directly with OpenGL ES. I started with this project:  http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/12/start-of-wavefront-obj-file-loader.html  (downloaded proj. from here) https://github.com/jlamarche/iOS-OpenGLES-Stuff/tree/master/Wavefront%20OBJ%20Loader 
And I kept improving code with more functionality. Problem is that I am kinda bad at math and started openGL only a month ago by just tinkering this project. That's why some "simple" things are hard to understand. I updated question with drawself function. All of what you mentioned already existed in that code.

Comment: What I did was - added functionality to rotate it, zoom it, import separated objects from single .obj file - and possibility to select each object, Added keyframe animations to objects. Mentioned task is - to select an object and show info about it. But - I need to draw a line to that object center (to place where object is visible). That's the thing I don't know - using it's center wavefront coordinates, rotation, position - calculate visual 2d coordinates. So - if You could simply write it as an answer with more description - you would help a lot to better understand what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, as I said, you'll need to apply the same transformations to the object center that are applied to the object's vertices by the graphics pipeline; only this time, the graphics pipeline won't help you - you'll have to do it yourself. And it involves some matrix calculations, so I'd suggest getting a good maths library like [the OpenGL Maths library](http://glm.g-truc.net/), which has the advatage that function names etc. are extremly similar to OpenGL.

**step 1: transform the center form object coordinates to modelview coordinates**

in your code, you set up your 4x4 modelview matrix like this:

```
// Load the identity matrix to restore to origin
glLoadIdentity();

// Translate to the current position
glTranslatef(currentPosition.x, currentPosition.y, currentPosition.z);

// Rotate to the current rotation
glRotatef(currentRotation.x, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glRotatef(currentRotation.y, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glRotatef(currentRotation.z, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

you need to multiply that matrix with the object center, and OpenGL does not help you with that, since it's not a maths library itself. If you use glm, there are functions like rotate(), translate() etc that function similiar to glRotatef() & glTranslatef(), and you can use them to build your modelview matrix. Also, since the matrix is 4x4, you'll have to append 1.f as 4th component to the object center ( called 'w-component' ), otherwise you can't multiply it with a 4x4 matrix.

Alternatively, you could query the current value of th modelview matrix directly from OpenGl:

```
GLfloat matrix[16]; 
glGetFloatv (GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, matrix);
```

but then you'll have to write your own code for the multiplication...

**step 2: go from modelview coordinates to clip coordinates**

from what you posted, I can't tell whether you ever change the projection matrix ( is there a glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION ) somewhere? ) - if you never touch the projection matrix, you can omit this step; otherwise you'll now need to multiply the transformed object center with the projection matrix as well.

**step 3: perspective division**

divide all 4 components of the object center by the 4th - then throw away the 4th component, keeping only xyz.
If you omitted step 2, you can also omit the division.

**step 4: map the object center coordinates to window coordinates**

the object center is now defined in normalized device coordinates, with x&y components in range [-1.f, 1.f]. the last step is mapping them to your viewport, i.e. to pixel positions. the z-component does not really matter to you anyway, so let's ignore z and call the x & y component obj_x and obj_y, respectively.

the viewport dimensions should be set somewhere in your code with `glViewport( viewport_x, viewport_y, width, height )`. from the function arguments, you can then calculate the pixel position for the center like this:

```
pixel_x = width/2 * obj_x + viewport_x + width/2;
pixel_y = height/2 * obj_y + viewport_y + height/2;
```

and that's basically it.

Comment: also, something I forgot to mention: doing it like this, you might end up with pixel values that are outside of the viewport - this will only happen if the object is translated / rotated in such a way that it's center lies outside of the view frustum.

Comment: If exported wavefront .obj  object was placed with offset from center - in iPhone it will appear with an offset, although it's current position will be 0. Also - when rotating, it will rotate around imaginary 0,0,0 (so it will not rotate around visible object center but that real offset center.) (I hope you can understand what I tried to tell) - Question is - will this still return correct visible object center or offset center? Because - Objects that I use are exported with offsets from center point.

Comment: no, you have to know the offset, otherwise this won't work. model files with a hardcoded offset are a bit weird - they make proper positioning in the scene hard. Maybe you could estimate the center by calculating a bounding box and using the box center instead? this is of course not ideal for arbitrary objects.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought. I figured out - I can get that offset by counting together all x values (y values separately, and z values separately) from object - then divide by point count. Thank You for your time explaining it all to me! I have now enough information to continue experimenting!